# InputText retorna null

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, aplicação-web

Fala galera, to com um problema que não sei mais o que fazer. A minha ideia foi ter um Checkbox que ao marcar mostraria um campo e ao desmarcar esconderia esse campo, para isso usei o rendered e ajax, Porém quando eu marco esse Checkbox mesmo que eu escreva algo no input que ele mostra o valor enviado é sempre null. Podem me ajudar?

.XHTML

```
<h:panelGroup>
                    <b><h:outputText value="Possui Deficiência? " /></b>
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                        value="#{controllerAluno.alunoCadastrar.deficiente}"
                        id="checkDeficiencia" immediate="true">
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="campoEspecifique" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <br />
                <h:panelGroup id="campoEspecifique">
                    <b><p:outputLabel value="Especifique:"
                            rendered="#{controllerAluno.alunoCadastrar.deficiente}"/> </b>
                    <p:inputText
                        rendered="#{controllerAluno.alunoCadastrar.deficiente}"                         
                        value="#{controllerAluno.alunoCadastrar.deficiencia}"/>                         
                </h:panelGroup>
```

MBean

```
public void inserir() throws Exception
{

    System.out.println("É Deficiente? " + this.alunoCadastrar.isDeficiente());
    System.out.println("Qual? " + this.alunoCadastrar.getDeficiencia());
    System.out.println("ID? " + this.alunoCadastrar.getId());
    System.out.println("Nome? " + this.alunoCadastrar.getNome());
    System.out.println("Sexo? " + this.alunoCadastrar.getSexo());
    System.out.println("Data? " + this.alunoCadastrar.getData_Nascimento());
    System.out.println("Turma? " + this.alunoCadastrar.getTurma().getDescricao());
    AdicionarMensagem.retornaInfo("Aluno Adicionado com Sucesso!");
    this.alunoCadastrar = new Aluno();
    AlunoNegocio an = new AlunoNegocio();               
    if (an.inserir(this.alunoCadastrar)) {
        AdicionarMensagem.retornaInfo("Aluno Adicionado com Sucesso!");
        this.alunoCadastrar = new Aluno();
    }   
}
```

Isso é o que gera, porém eu informei um valor na deficiência e sempre vai null como falei anteriormente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algumas perguntas: Você realmente precisa do atributo `immediate=true` no checkbox ? Quando você está submetendo seu formulário, está usando `process` em alguma coisa ?

Comment: Mostre no xhtml o componente que envia o formulário.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar assim no seu ajax:

```
 <p:ajax partialSubmit="true" .... />
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu ajax coloque o `immediate`:

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="campoEspecifique" immediate="true"/>
```